# REST practices for validating a resource

Tags: rest

I am currently implementing a "token" REST service.

A token is just a string, built from some parameters, which is then hashed and expires after a certain amount of time.

I want to have an endpoint in my REST service which can validate a token, but I'm not 100% sure how to implement it in a RESTful way

1. I assume this should be done via GET because it doesn't change state and so long as i set cache controls correctly it can be cached for a sensible amount of time. i.e `mysite.com/token/kjfhwekjfwekj`
2. What are the appropriate return codes? I would assume 200 if it is valid, but what about if it's invalid? I feel a 400 is wrong because although the resource itself is invalid, the client isn't calling the endpoint incorrectly. Is 404 correct here? If we think of tokens as short lived resources I guess so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GET` is the correct HTTP verb to check a token.

Assuming that 'invalid' for a token means that:

1. it never existed, or
2. it existed but does not exist anymore.

Do you want the client of your service to be able to *know the difference*?

- If **yes**, return `404 Not Found` for case 1, and `410 Gone` for case 2.
- If **no**, return `404 Not Found`.

If the token exists, `200 OK` is correct.

Comment: It might also be invalid because a user just tried to make a token up i.e /token/iamguessingatokenname, but I assume 404 is still ok for this because it's still technically a resources that has never existed

Comment: @qui True, but how can the server distinguish between a token that never existed an a maed up token? I don't think it can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be Restful, probably the best is to use the HEAD method, because you are not requesting for a token, you just want to know if the token exists.

HEAD method is for requesting metadata of a resource. GET is for retrieve resources

Answer (score 0):

The server has the symmetric hashing key; it can be used to validate if the incoming token was generated by someone other than itself.