# Practical REST services design questions

Tags: rest

I am working on a project whose current stable version is written using JSP/Servlets and it needs to be re-written as Single Page Application using client side MVC framework Backbone.js and REST services on server written using spring web MVC. Same set of REST services should be used for iOS application written using Objective C.

This is the first time I am writing non-trivial REST services and I have gone through a book on Rest and many blog entries as well as many StackOverflow entries like following:

- [Non-CRUD operations in a RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850187/non-crud-operations-in-a-restful-service)
- [Best practice for partial updates in a RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443324/best-practice-for-partial-updates-in-a-restful-service)
- [REST practices for validating a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230237/rest-practices-for-validating-a-resource)
- http://abstractfinal.blogspot.in/2007/04/restful-urls-for-non-crud-operations.html
- http://www.infoq.com/articles/designing-restful-http-apps-roth

I have not yet found any definite answer to all of my questions which I encountered during design of the REST services. I have done design of those services but I want to validate my design.

1. My application has Car as a main resource. So my URI to get all cars becomes something like

   ```
   GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars
   ```

   URI to get a particular car is

   ```
   GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/MH12-1234
   ```

   where `MH12-1234` is id of the car.

   My trouble begins when I want to get all such cars those are manufactured by Ford and Hyundai in 2010. Probable URI in my opinion becomes either

   ```
   GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/search/Ford;Hyundai/2010
   ```

   or

   ```
   GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/car/search?make=Ford,Hyundai&year=2010
   ```

   1. Which one of these is right?
   2. I could not imagine "search" as resource so I am keeping car as resource and search as a operation on it. Is this against REST ideology?
2. My car resource has many possible operations, e.g. painting a car, washing a car etc. URIs of those operations look like following to me.

   ```
   POST http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/MH12-1234/paint/yellow/glossy
   ```

   or

   ```
   POST http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/MH12-1234/paint?color=yellow&finish=glossy
   ```

   1. Which one of these is right? and should I send entire car object as a part of request body?
   2. Some people suggest that operation name should be sent as custom attribute of request header. So in my case `paint` will go inside request header. In such case, where do I send information like `color=yellow` and `finish=glossy`? As a part of request body or header?
3. Once client reads the car resource, it may want to change its wheel to some other suitable wheel. So URI for this operation may look like

   ```
   GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/car/MH12-1234/replace/wheel/rear-left
   ```

   This is basically replacing rear left wheel with some other suitable wheel.

   1. Is this right approach?
   2. Should this service return entire car or just the new wheel?
4. User who is playing with the car object in the client interface may try various operations on the car. E.g. user may paint it yellow and then paint it green and replace multiple wheels and then ultimately click on save. For each action that user initiated I have to post the entire car object or part of it to the server. So is it OK to send the part of it to avoid package size on the wire?

   Now those request are sent as either PUT or POST and server carries out those operations in memory and returns modified car object. Now car resource is getting sent as request and car object is received as response. Is this a valid scenario?

   If yes, then in both cases (save button click or any operation) I have to POST or PUT the same car resource to the server. I want to actually save car resource to database when save button is clicked and in case of other operations I just want to carry out the operation in server memory and return modified resource. How do I differentiate on the server about the user clicking on save as in both cases I PUT or POST the resource?

Comment: Question is too broad, try break it into many little questions

Comment: @ssedano Sorry for not breaking it in little ones. I have 4 related questions. So thought of posting all of them in same thread. If possible answer any one of them.

Comment: it was only a suggestion of course you can keep this question open as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using operations.

Just modify attributes of your car client-side and do a PUT to save changes.

Server-side should then verify if it's coherent (like do not put a paint instead of gas) and saves or eventually return a HTTP error.

For searches / filters, I like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933902/1665540).

Anyway, REST is more of a general guideline and you don't need your API to follow REST  principles literally.

Do what you think is more logical for your data, following REST guidelines, not constraining your API to it.

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my question. Related to operation question, are you suggesting that on client side I should update the color to yellow and now send the entire car object to server and server code should find out that car was earlier red and now is yellow so it should carry out paint operation?

Comment: What should matter is not the operation of painting, itself, but the color of the paint the client told you it was. If you're in a particular case and the operation is what matters then operation should be a ressource itself, or a subressource of a car.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think in REST services like http resquest, so

1. I will choose **GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/car/search?make=Ford,Hyundai&year=2010** because is more similar to GET request. Also try to think in a request for all the cars of year 2010 with the other format GET http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/search//2010
2. The correct will be send **POST http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/MH12-1234** and in the body of the post the information of the request, in the format thar to choose, the usual is xml o json. 
   My advise is that you must use another url for this service, something like **http:/host:port/mywebappname/service**. Try to isolate the urls: cars must be for serach cars or add a new car, not for an appointment at the garage operation.
3. the best in this case is use a PUT service, that in REST is add or modify an item, but usually is used only as modify an item, and is simillar to the POST services: **PUT http:/host:port/mywebappname/cars/MH12-1234** and the modifications in the body.
4. Depend that you want: if the web is for buy cars, maybe you you only must add a new car when the selection is finished; if is for a garage an the modifications implies send the car to the garage, maybe must be another service and when the car is finished that the mechanics modify the car.

Comment: For operation question, are you suggesting me to have URI like http:/host:port/mywebappname/paintservice/MH12-1234/yellow/glossy?

Comment: yes and no: the url will be 

http:/host:port/mywebappname/paintservice/MH12-1234/ and in the body of the request, for example in json {"color":"yellow", "touch": "gloswsy"}.

Or maybe something more generic http:/host:port/mywebappname/services/MH12-1234/ and in the body {"service": "paint", "color":"yellow", "touch": "gloswsy"}

and if you want more than one service in the same request {services : [{"service": "paint", "color":"yellow", "touch": "gloswsy"}, {"service" : "clean"}]}